# Easiest Way to Move Dead-Lettered Messages back to Processing Topic?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

When a message cannot be processed, we are placing the message on a dead-letter topic.  We now have several hundred messages on the dead-letter topic that were placed there due to a bug in our application.  Now that we have fixed the causing bug, what is the easiest way to "move" all messages from the dead-letter topic back to the normal topic to be reprocessed?

In RabbitMQ, you would just move the messages via the RabbitMQ dashboard; is there an equivalent in kafka, or do you need to code a separate application to move the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not able to replay the original topic, which you could do by resetting the offset, you'll need a mechanism to replay from the DLT (Dead-letter topic)

#### Bad news

There is no such functionality - available as UI similar to Rabbit's "move message" shovel functionality. We stumbled upon this as well and we ended up with building a console tool to "shovel" the messages: source - destination topic.

Keep in mind the default retention period in Kafka is, I believe 7 days. It's pretty short - although such a tool can be quickly realized.

We decided to move away from the dead-letter mechanism in our landscape which works surprisingly well together with fast deploy-able (and fixable) units.

If you have KSQL or [kafka streams](https://chrzaszcz.dev/2019/08/kafka-streams/) available, then that's also an option. But still, there's nothing out of the box similar as RabbitMQ available.